# Using regexpr in R with multiple strings affirmation and negation

Tags: regex, r, perl

I am grepping at a column of notes. Looking for the presence of some strings and the absence of others. The expression looks like

```
toMatch <- c("words", "i", "want", "to")
notToMatch <- c("not", "in", "my", "res")
insert <- paste(paste(toMatch, collapse="|"), "!", paste(notToMatch, collapse="!"), sep="")
regexpr(insert, df$notes, ignore.case=T)
```

It seems to me that regexpr will count

```
printNotes = +1 presence and -1 absence
```

and if that expression evaluates to printNotes > 0, it returns a value other than -1 (which in regexpr indicates not found).

Any suggested syntax for regexpr to return -1 if any of the notToMatch "!" arguments return TRUE?

Thanks much!

Comment: I think you might be confused about regex patterns. There is no "!" operator in R regex patterns, at least I cannot find any such documentation. You also seem to expect us to know what is on your computer, but only you can see "df".

Comment: I use the ! as a logical operator in the same manner | is used as a logical operator. The insert expression reads..."words OR i OR want OR to NOT not NOT in NOT my NOT res" and looks in R like... "words | i | want | to ! not ! in ! my ! res". I use df as an example data frame. The issue is that if df$notes has an entry... "words i not want to" for instance, then the regexpr result would be > -1, and thus not what I want to happen. I am trying to get regexpr to return -1 if any of the "NOT" operations are TRUE.

Comment: There is no regex "!" operator. It's just not a special character. There is a "^" regex-operator which is somewhat similar to a logical NOT at least when used in character-classes, but you are instead throwing in "!" in a `paste` call expecting it to be a logical-`NOT`.  When you are using an operator in a context where it is not defined, you will _not_ get results in line with your expectations.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `grepl()` to get a logical vector of where the strings have matched and then `sum()` that vector to see the number which are matches. You can do the same thing (roughly) with `grep()` and counting the length of the resultant vector but `grepl()` behaves a bit more consistently.

If you want to get the inverse of any match you can do `!grepl("match", x)` and it will show the logical inverse.

If you *specifically want it to return `TRUE` or `!` you can do something like `ifelse(grepl("m", letters), TRUE, "!")` which searches the `letters` constant (all 26 lower-case english letters) for "m" and returns TRUE on a match and "!" on a failure to match.